# Selected Item in Without using the method "change" in dropdown list in Jquery and Asp.Net Core?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core

I have this code that works well but ...

```
$("#maincategory").change(function () {
    $("#ParentId").empty();
    $.getJSON("/AdminPanel/Category/GetSubCategory/" + $("#maincategory :selected").val(),
        function (data) {
            $.each(data,
                function () {
                    $("#ParentId").append('<option value= ' + this.value + '>' + this.text + '</option>');
                })
        }

    )
});
```

Html code :

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">choose main category</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="maincategory" asp-items="ViewBag.maincategory">
                        </select>

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">choose first category</label>
                        <select class="form-control" asp-for="ParentId">
                            
                        </select>
                        <span asp-validation-for="ParentId" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
```

I want to give maincategory a value And get ParentId automatically  from controller ?

Comment: Could you please tell me why you don't want to use change to trigger to the dropdownlist changed method.